# App sounds doesn't sound with ringer off even with kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, audio

I'm making a soundboard app, everything goes fine but I have one issue, the sounds doesn't play if the ringer is off.

I have tried this:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
```

I'm using the AVFoundation Framework

The code to play the button is this:

```
- (IBAction)queChin:(id)sender {
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"chin", CFSTR ("m4a"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

I have searched this topic but I couldn't find any answer that works. Maybe I'm missing something?

As alternative I can put an alert to the user saying "hey, turn your ringer on" but I don't know how to detect if the phone is silenced.

Any hints?

Thank you.

Comment: You might need to set up a different kind of audio session for that (as if your app was playing music).

Comment: Following Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4-SW1) AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback is the correct category to use, I'm initializing the audio session in the viewDidLoad method. This topic is full of frustration even in the Apple Dev Forum :(

Comment: Perhaps doesn't work because I'm using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found out, you can't play System sounds with AudioServicesPlaySystemSound even if you initialize an Audio Session using this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
```

System sounds are meant to remain silent if the user mutes the device.

I ended up using AVAudioPlayer and that solved the problem.

Old code using System Sound:

```
- (IBAction)queChin:(id)sender {
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"chin", CFSTR ("m4a"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);//prevents memory leak
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

New code using AVAudioPlayer:

```
- (IBAction)queChin:(id)sender {

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"chin" withExtension:@"wav"];
_chingosound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
_chingosound.delegate = self;
[_chingosound prepareToPlay];
[_chingosound play];
}
```

You MUST initialize the audio session to play sounds with the ringer off.